# Accessing array of hash in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have problem with accessing a hash in each element of array after creating it but it gave the last element. What should I do to access all the elements of my array?

```
@stem = ();
for($i=0;$i<2;++$i){
    push @stem,{u1=>1 , u2 => 2 , u3 => 3};
}
@ants = ();
$count = 0;
for($i=0;$i<scalar(@stem);++$i){
    @allowed = ();
    %hash = ();

    for($j=0;$j<scalar(@stem);++$j){
        push @allowed,{stem=>++$count,hinfo=>++$count};
    }
    %hash = ( allowed=>\@allowed ,solution=>++$count);
    push (@ants,\%hash);

}

for($i=0;$i<scalar(@ants);++$i){
    %test = %{$ants[$i]};
    print "=>",$test{solution},"\n";
    @temp = @{$test{allowed}};
    for($j=0;$j<scalar(@temp);++$j){
        print $j,":",$temp[$j]->{stem}," ",$temp[$j]->{hinfo},"\n";
    }
}
```

output:
=>21
0:16 16
1:18 18
2:20 20
=>21
0:16 16
1:18 18
2:20 20

Comment: Start with `use strict; use warnings;` and don't use global variables everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is just one variable `@allowed` and one variable `%hash`, where you take references to them you are always getting the same value (which was cleared and set in the final iteration of the loop).

Declare them inside the loop, and you will be get references to new variables each time through the loop:

```
for($i=0;$i<scalar(@stem);++$i){
    my @allowed;
    my %hash;

    for($j=0;$j<scalar(@stem);++$j){
        push @allowed,{stem=>++$count,hinfo=>++$count};
    }
    %hash = ( allowed=>\@allowed ,solution=>++$count);
    push (@ants,\%hash);
}
```